# Excel dependent lists

Tags: excel, list

[spreadsheet issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujIxn.png)

The above image is of a spreadsheet I am trying to make for a warehouse that houses multiple types of donated items. I have selected the Item weight, the name of the item and the classification code. 
As you may be able to see the name is a list. I want to link the other  2 cells so that when the list cell has a set value the other 2 cells will pick their accommodating value.
So paper displays one weight and code, card displays a different weight and code and fabric displays a 3rd set. Please note that the list is likely to be expanded so if possible I would like to use the most easily expanded system that I can.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I need to ask.

The weight and category are also to select? or Every item has only 1 category and weight?

If the latter, a VLOOKUP on these cells would do the trick, as for the Item name list i'd suggest you to create another sheet where you follow this:

Column A the name
Column B the weight
Column C the category

When you make the list use a formula. Let's say your sheet with this data is called "Data" so it would be like:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$1;1;0;COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1)
```

As for the VLOOKUP, you can do this:

```
=VLOOKUP($A3;'DATA'!$A:$C;ITEMCOLUMN;FALSE)
```

Where ITEMCOLUMN --> 2 = weight and 3 = Category if you followed my example

Hope this helps. If not, tell me exactly about the category and weight columns.

Comment: I'm glad it did, if you don't mind to accept the answer as good I'd appreciate it.